# Is UEFI required to boot from a GPT SSD?

Tags: ubuntu, uefi, grub2, gpt

I've spent the past day trying to get GPT to work with my installation/motherboard.
I have a [Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 rev1.0](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3894#ov) motherboard, and I'm trying to install Ubuntu over two drives, an SSD and an HDD with the following partition scheme:

SSD: (120Gb GPT):
<sub>5mb - unpartitioned boot_grub

10Gb - `/boot`

50Gb - `/`</sub>

HDD: (3Tb, GPT):
<sub>25Gb - swap

25Gb - `/var`

100Gb - `/media/Music`

1.5Tb - `/home`

100Gb - `/opt`

100Gb - `/usr/local`</sub>

However, when I reboot, my BIOS sticks at the "Loading Operating System.." screen. I've tried switching between AHCI and IDE for my drives, but it doesn't seem to help, so I'm left wondering if my motherboard can't read GPT disks.

Comment: Do you have an EFI system partition, MBR ID 0xEF? It doesn't seem you have one. UEFI requires an ESP to boot.

Comment: @Marco, I do not. Is there anything special I need to do after creating one?

Comment: UEFI only supports GPT and BIOS only supports MBR.  UEFI based systems are only able to boot MBR partitions because of a legacy mode if they have one.   You might want to place a question in your question.

Comment: @Ramhound It's not true that BIOS only supports MBR. Many of the newer BIOS can boot from GPT.

Comment: @Marco provide the proof everything I know about MBR and GPT says othwrwise

Comment: @Marco Your statement is not valid. _"Many of the newer BIOS can boot from GPT."_ That's because 99% of the new boards that are produced are UEFI **with BIOS** (Legacy).

Comment: A basic BIOS just reads the first sector of the disk and transfers control to it; it does nothing with partition tables. Some more advanced BIOSes do try to parse partition tables and often cause problems as a result. The EFI/GPT and BIOS/MBR ties are in *Windows*. Linux, FreeBSD, and several other OSes can boot fine on BIOS-based computers from GPT disks. I've done this myself on several computers. See [my Web page on the subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/booting.html) for more information.

Comment: @Ramhound I set up several systems with GPT partition scheme, using UEFI and BIOS and it mostly works fine, given a not too ancient system. The last one was a Lenovo Thinkpad L412.

Comment: @cbabb GPT partition tables work on UEFI systems, UEFI system in BIOS emulation mode and older BIOS systems without UEFI. Did you try it? If it didn't work, it might be a buggy BIOS (which is actually not uncommon).

Comment: @Marco - I still maintain you didn't boot a GPT partition with a system which only had BIOS and not UEFI.

Comment: I can't speak for Marco, but I can say with 100% certainty that I have booted from GPT disks on BIOS-based computers. See the [Wikipedia entry on the BIOS Boot Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_Boot_partition) for evidence. To quote it, "the BIOS Boot partition is a partition on a data storage device that may be used by standard BIOS-based machines in order to boot when the partition table of the device is a GPT label." Note that I'm the author of [GPT fdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) and of [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) so I know this subject well.

Comment: You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink. Thanks for the suppport @Rod and many thanks for the great tools you wrote. I use them regularly, mostly sgdisk (to create GTP labels for my BIOS systems, or was it UEFI … ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Gigabyte's website, this board (Rev 1.0) is BIOS; therefore it only supports MBR. Rev 3.0 of this model and onwards is UEFI based with Legacy mode. With your current board, you can not use a GPT disk. If you want to use this setup, you would need to upgrade. Cross flashing in this case is not possible either; even though the products are identical. Rev 1.0 is Award (BIOS) and Rev 3.0 is AMI (UEFI).

[GA-990FXA-UD3 (rev. 3.0)](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4397#sp)

Comment: This is incorrect; see my response.

Answer (score 4):

The Web page linked to in the original post includes the following feature specification:

- Patented DualBIOS with Hybrid EFI technology for 3TB HDD support

The Hybrid EFI is a very buggy EFI implementation that's built as a layer atop a traditional BIOS. I've got a computer with this setup myself, and the [firmware implementation is pretty awful.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gb-hybrid-efi) It *is* possible to boot it from a GPT disk, in both BIOS mode and in EFI mode (I've done so in both modes), although I've never tried it with a 3TB hard disk, so that may create some additional wrinkles. I'm not sure offhand what's causing your system to fail to boot; it could be any of dozens of problems, such as a missing boot loader, a misconfigured boot loader, or a BIOS bug.

One common requirement on some EFI-based systems booting from GPT disks in BIOS mode is to have an MBR partition marked as active. Since GPT includes a "protective MBR" with a single partition of type 0xEE, setting that partition active sometimes works around boot problems. You'll need to use an MBR-only tool, such as all but the very latest versions of Linux's `fdisk`, to do this; or you can use a *very* recent version of `parted` to set a flag on the disk as a whole. (I don't recall the flag's name, offhand, but it is `not` the `boot` flag, which identifies an EFI System Partition (ESP).) OTOH, if you decide to try EFI-mode booting, you should probably *not* set this flag. If you try the flag first and then move on to EFI-mode booting, remove it before you go on to the EFI-mode booting.

Note that you could also convert your SSD to MBR form using `gdisk` and leave your 3TB spinning disk as GPT. It's conceivable that this would help your computer work past whatever problems it's got. If you do this, you'll probably have to re-install your (BIOS mode) GRUB. Even Windows has no problems with systems that mix MBR and GPT disks, so long as the boot disk is in the right mode for the firmware.

The other approach is to try an EFI-mode boot. This is possible, but it's awkward on this board. One easy way to try it might be to download the CD-R or USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a suitable medium. When you boot from it, rEFInd should show you a set of boot options. If one of these boots into Linux, then you can try a disk-based installation. To do this, you'll need to shrink one of your partitions by ~550MiB and create an [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) in that space. Mount that partition at `/boot/efi` and install the Debian package of rEFInd. Unfortunately, one of the bugs of the Hybrid EFI is that it tends to forget its boot entries, so you might then want to type `sudo mvrefind.sh /boot/efi/EFI/refind /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT`. This will rename rEFInd to boot using the EFI fallback filename, which will probably be more reliable on this board.

One more point: The downloads page for your board includes a "beta BIOS," which is *probably* a more reliable non-BIOS-based EFI. I can't promise it will work any better than whatever you've got now, but it might. (OTOH, if you're already running this "beta BIOS," it could be that returning to an earlier Hybrid EFI version would help fix your problem.)